# How to find a number corresponding to a change in other numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra

I assume it may be rather a trivial question but can someone "educate me" please:

I have 2 pairs of numbers:

`60 000` (which corresponds to a 96th percentile and represents monetary value) and `72 000` (which corresponds to a 97th percentile and represents monetary value)

and `248` (which corresponds to a 96th percentile and represents volume) and `207` (which corresponds to a 97th percentile and represents volume)

What I need to find out (mathematically) is what is the volume for the monetary value of `65 000`.

```
                   P96   P97
Monetary value    60000 72000
Volume             248   207
```

Can someone please explain to me how this calculation pans out (I'm using excel for calculations). Please explain it as you were teaching someone for the first time (I intend to apply this to other situations as well so it would be helpful for the future).

I think that percentiles are irrelevant, the relevant part is where the numbers are changing and what the volume would be for the monetary value of `65 000`.

Much obliged
West

PS. To moderators who put my question on hold, I have already answered it (below). Why is it blocked now, cos you didn't get point for answering it?

Comment: There is no mathematically necessary relationship between "monetary value" and "volume", so you cannot infer a value for volume corresponding to one for monetary value without more assumptions.  Apparently you are thinking of a situation where volume decreases as monetary value increases, but a mathematical model for such a relationship is based on information about the underlying economics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I have developed is based on the following:

```
                   P96   P97
Monetary value    60000 72000
Volume             248   207
```

---

I have transposed the values to

```
Volume Monetary Value
 248     60 000
 207     72 000
```

Following the basic "rate of change" process:

60 000 - 72 000 = -12 000

248 - 207 = 41

-12 000/41 = -292.7

(65 000 - 60 000)/-292.7= -17.08

Thus, at 65k the volume should equal 248 - 17 = 231

```
Thus, at 65k the volume = 231 units
```

Can someone verify my logic?

PS. Excel:

```
230.92=248+(65000-60000)/((60000-72000)/(248-207))
```

Comment: It is correct. Colleague, mathematician (I met with personally) just confirmed. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Is the relation between the volume and the monetary value linear?

Comment: Also, you don't have to interpolate manually of you have excel. You could plot the data and let excel make a trend line. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-trend-or-moving-average-line-to-a-chart-fa59f86c-5852-4b68-a6d4-901a745842ad

Comment: @Insertnamehere Thanks, I'll take a look now.